# What database uses "H??X!$L<" ("ndcy"? ) as a Magic Header String?

Tags: database, file-format

I'm trying to determine what database Cydia uses for metadata on jailbroken iOS devices. There is no `file` program available to offer a possible answer.

Here's the head of the cat:

```
iPad:~/root# cat /private/var/mobile/Library/Cydia/metadata.cb0 
H??X!$L<????)D#??
 tC????K1??.t#)?(?
???.??w2?l%@A?  ?%??4\<.??)?C
```

Is this a Magic String? Does anyone recognize the database or the markers?

---

Based on  TOOGAM's comments, this provides more information. ***`6e-64-63-79`*** is ***`ndcy`***, but it does not appear to be a magic string. That may strike the first question.

```
# cat /private/var/mobile/Library/Cydia/metadata.cb0 | od -x | head 
0000000 6e64 6379 0000 0000 0d84 003d 0000 0000
0000020 0000 0000 e142 0000 1704 001e 0000 0000
0000040 0000 0000 0000 0000 24fc 0024 0000 0000
0000060 4c10 003c dafc 0012 0000 0000 cc88 0029
0000100 0000 0000 0000 0000 2344 0019 91c0 000d
0000120 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 c348 0007
0000140 0000 0000 dd00 001e 2158 000c 0000 0000
0000160 0000 0000 0000 0000 39c4 0004 0000 0000
0000200 4b10 0031 0000 0000 f2f8 000e 0000 0000
0000220 2e14 0004 2374 0029 07d8 0019 a128 000d
```

---

I understand mobile devices are off-topic. I believe a general question about databases, file formats and the magic strings they use are OK for super user.

For example, here's SQLite's [magic header string](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html):

> 1.2.1 Magic Header String
>
> Every valid SQLite database file begins with the following 16 bytes
>   (in hex): 53 51 4c 69 74 65 20 66 6f 72 6d 61 74 20 33 00. This byte
>   sequence corresponds to the UTF-8 string "SQLite format 3" including
>   the nul terminator character at the end.

Comment: Would it be a well known one? They might just have cooked something up from scratch or mildly obfuscated a known one. I'd also give [trid](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) a shot to see if it recognises it

Comment: I have doubts that there are really that many ASCII code 63 (question marks).  It is more likely that the file viewer, which you are using, is showing some unrecognized Unicode characters.  If you can figure out what the actual characters are, that may make searches easier.  Unix's "od -x" can help, if that command is available.  As the software is GPLv3, there may be another way of answering this (by looking at what the software does, rather than trying to decipher data files).